# How to Control the Column Order in a Server-Side SQL Profiler Trace?

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling

I created a stored procedure that starts a server-side Profiler trace.  Originally, I generated the SQL script from profiler's File / Export / Script Trace Definition options.  I have since modified it a bit to make it friendlier.

The script does the following:

```
exec sp_trace_create... -- creates the trace
exec sp_trace_setevent <traceID>, <eventID>, <columnID>, 1... (many of these per event)
exec sp_trace_setfilter...(a few filters)
exec sp_trace_setstatus <traceID>, 1 -- starts the trace
```

When the trace is complete, and I examine the trace file, the trace columns appear in what looks like an arbitrary order.  It doesn't match the order of columns I am adding to each trace event.  I would prefer the columns to appear in a different order.

**Is there a way to control the order of the columns in the trace file when using a server-side trace?**

Our product runs on SQL Server versions 2005 through 2012, but answers requiring a specific database version are fine.

Also note that I'm aware of extended events, but I'm specifically looking for an answer about server-side profiler traces.

Comment: No, I don't think so, but you could maybe write the query such that the columns are explicitly listed in the order you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aaron Bertrand pointed out, there is no way to control the order of columns when written to a trace file.

It is possible to use the function [`sys.fn_trace_gettable`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx) to retrieve the trace data into a table and then select the data out of it in any order.

It is also possible to have the server-side trace save events to a table.  Select the "Save to table" option in the trace properties when [creating the trace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx).